# Problem with height in a Scaffold with SingleChildScrollView, Column, TabBar, and TabBarView

Tags: flutter, dart

i'm trying to build a page with multiple tabs and I can't seem to get the height to work, it eithers get infinite, or it does overflow / error 'Has Size'

I can't seem to find the answer.

This is the Widget Tree:

```
Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(
      'Title',
    ),
  ),
  body: SafeArea(
    child: Scrollbar(
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            TabBar(
              controller: _tabController,
              tabs: myTabs,
              isScrollable: true,
            ),
            Container(
              height: double.maxFinite,
              child: TabBarView(
                physics: BouncingScrollPhysics(),
                controller: _tabController,
                children: [
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text('Some text...\n' * 150),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Container(child: Text('Llamadas')),
                  Container(child: Text('Mensajes')),
                  Container(child: Text('Reservas')),
                  Container(child: Text('Cómo llegar')),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: I've managed to solve this issue using this: https://newbedev.com/tabbarview-with-variable-height-inside-a-listview

Answer (score 4):

A `SingleChildScrollView` gives its child infinite size in its scrollable direction (i.e. the bit that scrolls could theoretically scroll forever).

Also, a `Column` will try to make itself as tall as possible.

If you put a `Column` inside a `SingleChildScrollView`, these behaviors conflict: the `SingleChildScrollView` allows its child to be as tall as it wants, and the `Column` wants to be infinitely tall. So when it tries to layout, it will attempt to be an infinite size, and this is an error.

To fix it, you can give a concrete size to your `Column` by wrapping it in a `SizedBox` with a finite `height`, or you could tell the `Column` to only occupy the space it needs my setting `mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min` (however if anything inside your `Column` have infinite height, this won't work).

Comment: As you can see I do use a SingleChildScrollView and the Column does in fact have mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, but the children is a text * 150 so as you said it shouldn't be infinite... but it is. Any tips? I'm affraid it might have something to do with the TabBarView.
Thanks.

Comment: Take another look at your code, there is a `SingleChildScrollView` with a `Column` as it's `child`

Comment: Definitely the best explanation!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can try to put "Expanded" On your code.

```
Expanded(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    Container( ....)]))))
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to work, ive tried disabling the TabBarView (Wich i need) and it seems thats the problem:

SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                TabBar(
                  controller: _tabController,
                  tabs: myTabs,
                  isScrollable: true,
                ),
                Text('Some text...\n' * 150),
              ],
            ),
          ),

This would work, but i need the TabBarView... I don't understand what is happening tbh

Comment: @cgutierr have you tried NestedScrollView ?

Comment: Yes i've tried that, and it had a similar problem...

Comment: @cgutierr I'm sorry I didn't get your point. Now you want to disabled your tabbarview on SingleChildScrollView or you need it there? Your problem is on heiight or on tabbarview?

Comment: @cgutierr maybe you need try expanded() on your code

Comment: I wanted the TabBarView working, but the height got messed up, tried without it to see if it was a TabBarView problem, and it seemed like so.
This link was usefull:
https://newbedev.com/tabbarview-with-variable-height-inside-a-listview 

Not the exact thing i wanted, but close enough, it uses a IndexedStack